# Symfony2: How to access a service inside an extension's load() method?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

Is it possible to get the doctrine service inside a bundle extension?

I can access the container, but can't get the doctrine service.

```
...
class UltroExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container){
        $dm = $container->get('doctrine_mongodb');
    ...
    }
}
```

I get this error: The service definition "doctrine_mongodb" does not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container hasn't been built/compiled yet - that's why you only get a `ContainerBuiler` object passed to the `load()` method.

you can't get a service object from the builder as it's not holding the services but only the service **definitions** at that point.

Use a **[compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html)** instead. More information can be found in the documentation chapter **[Compiling the container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html)**.

Maybe your problem can be solved using a **[service factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)**, too.